# How to pronounce "linearly"?

Tags: pronunciation, adverbs, rhoticity

As the title states, how do I pronounce the word "Linearly"? I did some Google searching on this but I was not able to find any guidance.

Comment: Pronunciation varies by region.  [Here are some examples](http://www.forvo.com/word/linear/#en) of linear.  Just add "lee" to the end of those.

Comment: I'd go with "LIN ee er lee".

Comment: I’d be interested to know what the problem was for you with the word. Was it the quality of the vowels, or the pattern of stress(es), or something else?

Comment: Where I come from, /ˈlənjəlɪ/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CMU Pronouncing Dictionary gives an American English pronunciation for linearly:
http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict/?in=linearly&stress=-s

`L IH1 N IY0 ER0 L IY0`

In [International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) this would be `/ˈlɪniːɚliː/`

In the [American Heritage Dictionary-style pronunciation respelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English) it would be `\lĭnēərlē\`

In the [Wikipedia pronunciation respelling style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aPronunciation_respelling_key) it would be <sub><sup>LIN</sup></sub>-ee-er-lee

---

As has been discussed in other answers, in standard non-rhotic British English, the 'er' of the third syllable is pronounced non-rhotically—that is, indistinguishable from an ordinary schwa. However, there are a number of rhotic British English dialects with a substantial number of speakers which would pronounce the 'er' rhotically.

Comment: Does that mean *linearly* and *lineally* merge in BrE?

Comment: Looking back on this answer, I don't even know why I marked this one. I don't understand a single thing you've said :-( I don't know how to read the things you have put there. I know that dictionaries show pronunciation with those symbols, but I never understood that.

Comment: @RobertDailey I gave an answer using 4 of the most common systems for marking pronunciation, in that hope that if you were familiar with any system, you'd be familiar with one of them. In case you weren't, I also included links for each system to a page which explains it. I'm not sure what kind of answer you would expect to a question asking "how to pronounce <X>" that doesn't use some system of writing pronunciation.

Comment: @nohat What I normally do is look up audio pronunciations. That's what I find helpful. However at the time I asked the question I guess I didn't find any (I don't really remember, I asked this a long time ago).

Answer (score 4):

Probably `/'lɪnɪəlɪ/` (depending on your dialect of English). Four phonemes (sounds), anyway: LI-nee-uh-li.

In fact, there is some pronunciation help online: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/linear?q=linearly#linear__9 and it looks like ODO agrees with me as far as British English is concerned.

[Help on IPA symbols](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm)

Comment: It's only LI-nee-**uh**-li if you _pahk yah cah in Hahvahd yahd_.

Comment: @rsegal Much of British English is indeed non-rhotic, but it could be written `/'lɪnɪəʳlɪ/` to indicate the possibility of rhoticism (depending on your dialect of English).

Comment: @rsegal, even in non-rhotic dialects, the 'r' in car is pronounced: pahk yah car in Hahvahd Yahd. See [Linking R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_R)

Comment: @nohat while that may be the convention, a lot of Bostonians I know would have pronounced it "cah" under those circumstances, without a doubt. Further, I think it's good form to not get it confused with the word _[lineal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineal)_, which it undoubtedly would without the 'r' sound.

Comment: @nohat, Obviously, you haven't even read the wikipedia article about linking r. It does say that "not all non-rhotic varieties feature linking R."

Comment: @Alex The article on [Boston accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_accent) states "The Boston accent possesses both linking R and intrusive R". I will note, however, that I have met people from the Boston area who do not natively have a non-rhotic accent but will affect one on occasion or for certain words and phrases for regional solidarity. That is: a lot of people will fake it (and by not knowing all the subtleties like linking R, fake it incorrectly).

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the symbols, the Oxford English Dictionary gives it as `/ˈlɪnɪəlɪ/`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not :( I was hoping for someone to use common, simple words to help describe how to pronounce it (if that makes sense).

Comment: LIN-ee-er-lee should be a reasonably good phonetic spelling that works for most U.K. and U.S. dialects. (While 'er' is pronounced differently in the two countries, the same spelling works for both.) The OED's phonetic pronuciation seems to be LIN-near-lee, which I believe is not how I've heard it pronounced by Brits, and which disagrees with the Cambridge Learner's dictionary.

Comment: @PeterShor I concocted my IPA from how I pronounce it as a Brit, and it agrees with OED.

Comment: The 'r' is not sounded in British English, other than in some regional dialects, where speakers probably wouldn't use the word anyway.

Comment: @Barrie: Agreed. I thought that the word 'er' in U.K. English was pronounced like 'uh' is pronounced in the U.S.

Comment: @PeterShor: Mostly, yes, but again with regional variations.

Comment: Mine is a very mainstream mild Scottish accent, with a basis in RP, and I would certainly pronounce the 'er'. I wouldn't roll the r but it is there.

Comment: @Rory, yes Barrie's comment about rhotic BrE speakers not using the word verges towards being an offense against Scots, doesn't it?

Comment: hehehe - I never take it personally :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop: To set the record straight, I have a southern English accent, have never knowingly used the word 'linearly', and think it unlikely that I will ever have many opportunities to do so.

Comment: @Barrie Hahahahah - brilliant :-)

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/linear-algebra/id354869137) is one of those free MIT on-line lecture courses.  This one is on linear algebra.  It should use the word "linearly" quite a lot, I expect.  In particular, try Lecture 9.

Comment: That's along time to wait for that well deserved up-vote. I hope you enjoy it!