# Pronunciation of word "considered"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, accent, rhoticity

I have learned in school that letter 'r' is not sounded in the word 'considered', here's [an example](http://forvo.com/word/considered/#en).

But I have been watching the 'How I met your mother' series, and Ted have pronounced that with sounded 'r', like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgiBUhUgC6U).

Is it some kind of mistake/difference between accents?

Comment: The _rhoticity_ of an accent refers to whether or not certain _r_'s are pronounced in that accent.  See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pronounce "linearly"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78405/how-to-pronounce-linearly)

Comment: This post has been close-voted as a duplicate of [How to pronounce "linearly"? –](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78405/how-to-pronounce-linearly). That page does  not in any way answer this question. At all. In any way. Whatsoever. Even nearly.

Answer (score 3):

Most varieties of American English are *rhotic*. This means that speakers pronounce orthographic (written) 'r' regardless of the sounds around it.

In *non-rhotic* varieties of English - such as Southern Standard British English - orthographic 'r' is only pronounced if followed by a vowel. It doesn't matter if there is a double /r/ or not in the orthography:

- car / ka:
- car park / ka: pa:k
- car alarm /ka:r əla:m
- carrot / kærət
- racoon / ræ'ku:n

In the sentences above the 'r's in *car* and *car park* aren't pronounced becuase they're not followed by a vowel. In contrast the first 'r' in *car alarm* is pronounces because it is followed by the vowel at the beginning of alarm. The 'r's in *carrot* and *racoon* are also pronounced for the same reason.

The Original Poster is obviously learning about a non-rhotic variety of English, maybe RP. However, the American speaker in the clip they are listening to speaks a rhotic variety. The Original Poster would expect the 'r' in *considered* to be silent because it is followed by a /d/. However, in the rhotic speaker's English it needs to be pronounced.

Comment: [Park the car in Harvard Yard](http://www.npr.org/2015/08/25/434668684/testing-boston-authenticity-with-park-the-car-on-harvard-yard)

Answer (score 2):

At least in the central u.s. the "r" is very clearly pronounced.