# IPA, Accents, and dictionaries, British and American Phonetics

Tags: american-english, british-english, phonetics, phonemes

As a non native english speaker, I'm trying to work on my accent. I've taken a lot of bad habits so I'm trying to go back to the fundamentals meaning learning phonetics. But they seem very imprecise to me. For example the word **hand**.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hand

Here the UK seems to pronounce the **æ** like it's really a single sound and the USA pronounce it more like two sounds: starting like **hen** then joing the **~ha** sound. With such a big emphasis on the **hen** sound that if the word were pronounced quicker I think I would have heard it as **hen** with a **d**.

Now if I trust what I hear [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel), the USA seems to be right.

But this pronunciation seems to be very, very inconsistent. The word **cat** (same phonetics):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cat

Here we have the same kind of pronunciation variation but "reversed". The USA **cat** is closer to the UK's than the USA **hand** but we can still hear a little **hen** sound at the beginning.

Now, worse : **trap**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trap

Here the UK and the USA are strongly agreeing on disagreeing with the IPA pronunciation of **æ** pronunciation I linked before.

So, why two clearly different pronunciations have the same phonetics symbols ?

Why the same phonetic symbol can be pronounced so differently from a word to another within the same "accent" ?

Are phonetics simply unreliable and should only be used to know roughly how a word should be pronounced ?

Would the most effective method to be sure I pronounce a word correctly be to search on internet for video or audio samples of people pronoucing them in context ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are "fun" and "hulk" phonetically transcribed with the same vowel but pronounced differently?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450097/why-are-fun-and-hulk-phonetically-transcribed-with-the-same-vowel-but-pronou) Bottom line: [not all phonetically distinguishable vowel sounds are considered to be distinct "phonemes" of a language](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450269/2637) (from the answer there). We only need different symbols to distinguish ***phonemes***, not all the possible differences you might be able to ***hear***

Comment: And if you're looking for one, distinct US accent, you are out of luck. Pronunciation varies region by region - and in some cases, even town by town - and there are some sounds that I fear not even the IPA could reproduce accurately.

Comment: @WordNerdHouston - Pronunciation in the US doesn't vary nearly as much as it does in the UK.

Comment: Compare all the US and UK entries at https://forvo.com/word/hand/#en (not comprehensive). Only EdwinWalker sounds different to me. Try the others (cat and trap). You may be interested in the [trap/bath split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap-bath_split) which accounts for -some- variation in /æ/, but that affects mainly the RP variety of BrE.

Comment: @Mitch Whether or not an accent has the trap/bath split concerns the pronunciation of BATH words (e.g. bath, glass, ask, ample) -- they have [a:] in accents with the split and [æ] in accents without the split. This split doesn't concern the pronunciation of TRAP words.

Comment: Are you trying to describe vowel breaking, where some speakers (like in Southern American English) will elongate a vowel sound by interjecting a /j/-like break [hæjənd], or /æ/-raising, where the tongue moves up during pronunciation [hɛənd]?

Comment: What do you mean "the USA is right"? British people pronounce *hand* with a British accent (of which there are hundreds of regional variations), and Americans pronounce *hand* with an American accent (of which there are also hundreds of regional variations). *Neither way is "right".*

Comment: @PeterShor I meant right according to the /æ/ pronunciation I linked which I thought, before reading the comments, was supposed to be the only pronunciation.